# Combining multiple similar items on the Launcher

Tags: launcher

I can't find this, but it could be I'm not sure how to search for it. I have a lot of icons in my Launcher. Is there a way to combine some, i.e. Firefox and Chrome or LibreOffice and gedit or graphics editors in one "folder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic word is '[**Drawers**](https://launchpad.net/drawers)'

> A utility for organizing related items for easy launching from the
>   Unity dock. Drawers creates a launcher for the Unity panel that can
>   contain any combination of files, web links or directories. Just drop
>   a file on the launcher and it will be added. Left-clicking the
>   launcher "opens a drawer" with an icon view of each item for
>   launching. Right-clicking allows fast launching through quicklists.

https://launchpad.net/~ian-berke/+archive/ppa-drawers

To install through Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install drawers
```

You can see Drawers in action on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTwXwadnxUU)

More info on [WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/unity-stacks-application-drawers-gets.html)